# Cannot delete just created file

Tags: vb.net-2010

My application can create a directory, put a file in it from a ZIP file and then remove the ZIP file.
When I then try to delete that file, I get an Access Denied error even though nothing was done with it.
Here is the code:

```
 File.WriteAllBytes(OpslagLocatieDocumenten + myTicketNummer.ToString + "\documenten.zip", op.Documenten)
  Using zp As New ZipFile(OpslagLocatieDocumenten + myTicketNummer.ToString + "\documenten.zip")
    zp.FlattenFoldersOnExtract = True
    zp.ExtractAll(OpslagLocatieDocumenten + myTicketNummer.ToString, ExtractExistingFileAction.OverwriteSilently)
    zp.Dispose()
  End Using

  Try
    For Each itm As String In Directory.GetFiles(OpslagLocatieDocumenten + myTicketNummer.ToString)
      Try
        File.Delete(itm)
      Catch ex As Exception

      End Try
    Next

  Catch ex As Exception
  End Try
```

It looks a bit messy right now, but that is for testing purposes.
In the for-next part, right after writing the file from the ZIP, I try to delete the files.
At the moment there are two files in the directory, one ZIP and one PDF document from the ZIP.
The first file in itm is the PDF, it errors with an ACCESS DENIED. 
The second file in itm is the ZIP which gets deleted.
The PDF is 311 kb in size.
Via Windows explorer I can delete it without any problem, even with the application still running.

Why is my file being locked?
What can I do to by-pass or remove this lock?

rg,

Eric

Comment: Also why are you calling .Dispose on zp when the Using block will do that for you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the problem.

The file that was added to the ZIP had it's attribute set to READ ONLY.
So when the application writes the file, windows would, as it should, not allow the application to delete it.

Unfortunately, windows does allow to delete the file via windows explorer without a message that the file is read only.

Answer (score 0):

Have you also tried the `File.Kill(fileLocation)` method?